# What is the best solution for using transparent PNGs in Internet Explorer 6?

Tags: internet-explorer, png, internet-explorer-6

Lack of proper PNG support in IE6 is a well-known issue, with several solutions. There does not appear to be a clear best accepted practice or method.

What do you propose the best solution is, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I've found is [Unit PNG fix](http://labs.unitinteractive.com/unitpngfix.php). It's tiny, fast, and eliminates most of the issues found in other solutions.

Answer (score 3):

1) Eliminate the need for alpha transparency

Failing that

2) Javascript for those that are absolutely necessary.  [SuperSleight](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6) is one option, but there are many javascript implementations.

3) Depreciate IE6 or provide a separate CSS for IE6 users

IE6, thankfully, is declining so option 3 is actually reasonable now.

-Adam

Comment: Did you mean "deprecate"? Depreciate is good to though, in this case. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the *.png to *.gif with IrfanView for example.
But since GIF-Format can only display 256 colors it often is leading to quality-loss and color-steps :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [pngfix.js](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/bobosola/pnghowto.htm) to apply the appropriate filter to PNGs in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Any solution involves using DirectX AlphaImageLoader

I like [Twinhelix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/demo/) solution most

and [version 2.0](http://www.twinhelix.com/test/), still not thorougly tested, seems to work great with background PNG too.

You can't neglect IE 6.0 since it still makes more than 20% in browser market share.
GIF transparency is below par.

Answer (score 0):

Use PNG-8 for transparency as it will work with IE6.
It will act like a GIF image under IE6 while it allows for alpha transparency in more capable browsers.